# Skip array element in HTML

Tags: html, css, arrays, angular

I have an array of length 5 on which I'm looping over to create the rating scale as shown in the image below.  How can I skip iterating over the first element (1) of the array and only render the div for the last four elements of the array (2, 3, 4, 5). I tried slicing the array first and then render but it doesn't help. Is there any way that the element remains in the array and I can skip over it in the HTML.

```
  <div class="rating-type__pipe" #messageEl [attr.data-option-id]="opt._id" id="rating_id_right{{opt?._id}}"
                    *ngFor="let opt of positiveArray; index as i">
                        <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                            <span [ngStyle]="{'height': (i+1)*(100/positiveArray.length)+'%','opacity': (i+1)*(1/positiveArray.length)}" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                </div>
            <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">{{opt.text}}</div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice method to skip first element.

```
<div class="rating-type__pipe" #messageEl [attr.data-option-id]="opt._id" id="rating_id_right{{opt?._id}}"
    *ngFor="let opt of positiveArray.slice(1); index as i">
    <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
        <span [ngStyle]="{'height': (i+1)*(100/positiveArray.length)+'%','opacity': (i+1)*(1/positiveArray.length)}" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">{{opt.text}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a dummy div for the first element and now it works fine.